# How to show dynamically created element on mouse down

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.rollimgwrap` is a wrap for `.rollmark` and `.rollimgb` and this are all dynamically created

`.rollimgb` is hidden by default and I need it show while keeping a mouse down on `.rollmark`.

Here is my try - without success

**html**

```
<div class='rollimgwrap'>
<div class='rollmark'>MARK</div>
<img class='rollimgb' src='...' alt='img'>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.rollimgwrap .rollmark', function(e){
    $(this).parent().find('.rollimgb').show();
})
.on('mouseup', '.rollimgwrap .rollmark', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.rollimgb').hide();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '.rollimgwrap .rollmark', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('.rollimgb').show();
  })
  .on('mouseup', '.rollimgwrap .rollmark', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.rollimgb').hide();
  });

function addHtml() {
  $('.dynamic').append(`
  <div class='rollimgwrap'>
    <div class='rollmark'>MARK</div>
    <img class='rollimgb' src='...' alt='img' style='display:none;' />
  </div>
`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='add dynamic html' onclick='addHtml()' />

<div class='dynamic'>  
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the whole code as well, or make a live snippet

Comment: @Karan, just using ajax - getting the block of html code from server

Comment: @Karan see the update, pls

Comment: seems like it's working as you intended, isn't it?

Comment: @Karan, there is no `MARK` in your snippet

Comment: All works fine to be honest. I am not sure whats the issue is ?

Comment: @Karan I see, but really can't see any difference compared to my code which doesnt work

Comment: @qadenza Because nothing is wrong in your code. All should work fine.

Comment: I think you may need to use `$('.rollimgb').hide();` after `append`, because in your `html` it doesn't come as `style='display:none;'` so initially your `img` will be `visible`.

Comment: @Karan, it is hidden by css - `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your `mouseup` event is firing on another element (most likely the content that's being shown)

Try changing the `mouseup` event to listen on `document` and hide all `.rollimgb` elements.

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '.rollimgwrap .rollmark', function(e){
    $(this).parent().find('.rollimgb').show();
})
.on('mouseup', function(){
  $('.rollimgb').hide();
});
```